# Visual Studio deletes SafeImports on Startup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

We are using the MSBuild.ExtensionPack in our project files to do some enhancements to our project files in Visual Studio. On opening a project, we get the following warning:

> "The {application name} project file has been customized and could
>   present a security risk by executing custom build steps when opened in
>   Microsoft Visual Studio. If this project came from an untrustworthy
>   source, it could cause damage to your computer or compromise your
>   private information."

Options are to 1) Load Project for Browsing or 2) Load Project Normally.

We can suppress this message temporarily by adding a value entry for MSBuild.ExtensionPack to the following registry key,

```
HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ 8.0\MSBuild\SafeImports\
```

This is a solution found on MSDN and elsewhere. **However**, Visual Studio 2010 appears to delete the value I add when it starts up. Very frustrating. The value I am adding is

```
Name: MSBuild.ExtensionPack
Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks
```

I am wondering how I can prevent Visual Studio 2010 from deleting this value, or another way of suppressing the message.

Comment: You are supposed to put a .targets file in that registry key, not a .tasks file.

Comment: There is no .targets file for MSBuild Extensions that I'm aware of, I import the tasks file in my projects.

Comment: Go to : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Debugger\DisableAttachSecurityWarning
The value should currently be 0. By changing it to 1, this warning should suppress, I have not tired for your problem but it might solve your problem.

Comment: I'm in Visual Studio 2010, and the issue is not related to the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the solution proposed in: "[opening a vs2010 project from another location](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/06/opening-a-vs2010-project-from-another-location.aspx)" will work for your case:

The author says: *"Fixing this is quite easy, just select the project file in the Windows Explorer, right click and open the files properties and click the Unblock button to tell Windows, and Visual Studio, that you trust the file."*  (please see the post for a more detailed step-by-step instructions)

Note that in this [forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/87f61e60-547b-462b-8dde-144848b4682c) seems that you specifically have to run as administrator do get the option to unlock the project:

- Log on your Windows 7 with administrator account
- When launch Visual Studio 2010, please run it with administrator privileges 
  (Right-click the icon >> "Run as Administrator")

Comment: No, sorry, this is a different issue.